# Open another apps from Unity android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Is there anyway to open another applications from unity Android ?

Currently, I have two applications that are deployed in Android Device.

Both of them are made in Unity. *(lets name it App1 & App2)*.

I would like to open **App1** with a ButtonClick and its open **App2**.

I tried to link it with a bundle identifier(_e.g; com.example.App2 ) in my C# script but no result yet.

Comment: have a look at this. https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-ios-launch-from-within-a-unity-app-another-unity-app.222709/

Comment: How can i miss this... ?! 
@Zaki Thank youuuu very mucchhh !!
You are the man! (╭☞'ω')╭☞

Comment: no worries, enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

there is two ways to do that.
One is [Unity Deep Link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/deep-linking.html) and another one is adding native android extension.

I think deep link integration will be easy, just call the link when clicked on the button and the app will be opened.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).